# Node.js CLI to Webpage Wrapper

Tags: angularjs, node.js, command-line-interface

My company has a folder called tools... which has about 50 some CLI Tools our support agents use for various troubleshooting and reporting...

Company is getting bigger... giving every rep access to our source code just so they can run the tools is not ideal... Plus things like npm package dependencies happen and it's more maintenance than they want.

Ideally, I would create an internal only website that simply presents a dropdown of all the tools in the /tools folder. The webserver (like Express) would execute the scripts and then redirect the standard output to the screen... The kicker is I need to allow for standard input as well since the tools are somewhat interactive... they get to select choices.

[image]

I'm sure there are all kinds of security issues with this and I just want emphasize this would be for internal use only and run by trusted users.

I've seen various terminal emulators and projects like this but looked complicated to make it work for our use case.  I really just want to let people run a preset number of commands... I feel like this type of thing should exist and I just haven't stumbled upon it yet.

Alternatively... I've considered refactoring the tools to use something like swagger which would present the options for them to fill out but that too isn't ideal as we have conditional prompts...

Answer (score 0):

You could use [socket.io](https://socket.io/) and build a [node.js](https://nodejs.org/en/) app for specific required commands.

socket.io allows for client/server communications on webpage.

node.js allows for a framework where you can pass commands through.

Comment: provide more explanation to support your answer

Comment: what would you like more explanation on? implement the tools together on server.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to use [xterm.js](https://github.com/xtermjs/xterm.js) to create browser based terminal that can execute the CLI tools.